# creating a form that is present in header of site rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form in which users can subscribe to a mailing list. I want this form to

1. be present on every page
2. to be submitted via ajax

I am currently struggling on the first part. I found this useful stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466317/rails-3-2-create-a-form-thats-used-in-the-footer-of-every-page). However I stil have the same error as before

```
undefined method `mailing_lists_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001066599b8>:0x000001066589a0>
```

I dont see why I need a path just to get the form to appear on the page.

_header.html.erb

```
<h2>Join our Mailing List</h2>
        <%= form_for MailingList.new, html: { remote: true } do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/location', to: 'static_pages#location'
  get '/support', to: 'static_pages#support'
  post '/support', to: 'static_pages#create'
  get '/admin_index', to: 'guides#admin_index'

  resources :news
  resources :yearly_guides
  resources :guides
  resources :courses  
  resources :galleries do
    resources :exhibition_images
  end
```

EDIT: with my current understanding, I don't see how a route is completely necesarry in just getting to the form to show. I realise submitting it would require further implementation in my controllers, but just to get it to show, i dont see why.

Comment: You need a route because Rails translates `form_for MailingList.new` into a html form tag with wants to post to mailing_lists_path. If you do not want this Rails magic, do not use Rails but build the html form by yourself.

Comment: @spickermann can you point me to anything that might help?

Comment: The Rails Guides are always a good starting point: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: http://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form_for` helper expects an url, which you can specify manually if the path rails assumes by default is incorrect:

```
<%= form_for MailingList.new, url: '/sign_up', html: { remote: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

If you really want a form without an url, just write out the tag manually

```
<form>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sharagoz. 
this works now, and is sumbitted via ajax.